Prove existence of solution for IVP
I am trying to solve this ODE problem. I am studying for an exam.
Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be $C^1$ such that $|f(x)| \leq 1 + |x|^{\alpha}$. Consider the IVP
\begin{equation}
x' = f(x),\\
x(0) = 0.
\end{equation}
Show that if $\alpha \in [0,1]$, then the solution $x = x(t)$ exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Give an example with $\alpha > 1$ such that there is no solution defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
What I think I should do is try to show that $\int \frac{dx}{1 + |x|^{\alpha}}$ is integrable for $\alpha \in [0,1]$ but not for $\alpha > 1$, but I have no idea how to proceed. That nasty absolute value is not helping. What should the limits of integration be? Is there anything else I should be trying? Why is it not enough to say that since $f$ is $C^1$, then it is locally Lipschitz and hence, by the Picard-Lindelof theorem, there exists a unique solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You showed there exists a unique solution, but not that it is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tip for $\alpha \le 1$ : Think about Gronwall's Lemma. Tip for $\alpha > 1$: what ODE does $\tan$ satisfy ?

@G.Fougeron I'm assuming you mean the differential version of that lemma. I have no idea what to do with that. That lemma requires something like $u'(t) \leq \beta(t)u(t)$. I have nothing like that; and that absolute value around the $x$ does not let me do anything.

What ODE does $x^2$ satisfy?

G.Fougeron It satisfies $x′=2x$. I think I get your other comment. If I take $\alpha=2$, I get the solution $x(t) = \tan t$, which is not defined for all t. But I don't get this $x^2$ hint. Should I apply Gronwall to this? I'm sorry but I find this very difficult.
